# Compare two lists or datatable

Tags: c#

I have two excel sheets for employees,

one has the current status, one has the old status,

I want to compare them to check which employees have their status changed.

currently i have this:

```
var result = from x in data.Worksheet<Employee>("Tradesmen")
                         select x;
```

and this:

```
var resultNew = from x in dataNew.Worksheet<Employee>("Tradesmen")
                         select x;
```

where `result` is a datatable has the old status, and `resultNew` is a datatable has the current status.

#### What I tried

I tried change these datatable to lists like this:

```
masterEmployees = new List<Employee>();
            foreach (var row in result)
            {
                masterEmployees.Add(new Employee(row.Code, row.Name, row.WorkingStatus));
            }

 foreach (var row in resultNew)
            {
                newEmployees.Add(new Employee(row.Code, row.Name, row.WorkingStatus));
            }
```

where `Employee` is a a simple class with `Code`, `Name` and `WorkingStatus` field.

#### My question

I want to know which employees that their status changed so how can I do that in the `lists` ? of is it better to do that in `datatable` ?

Comment: Please spend of few minutes researching this there are plenty of solutions.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx

Comment: @RickS the link you provided is about string, my problem is about a class called `Employee` which has the string field `WorkingStatus` that I want to compare about

Comment: Learning how to take in information and apply it to your own situation is a really important skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    var result = new List<Employee>();
    var resultNew = new List<Employee>();

    var changed = (from i in result
                   join j in resultNew on i.Code equals j.Code
                   where i.WorkingStatus != j.WorkingStatus
                   select new { Name = i.Name, OldWorkingStatus = i.WorkingStatus, NewWorkingStatus = j.WorkingStatus        }).ToList();
```

Don't forget

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Update**

If you do this i think you'll be ok(the same for the resultNew variable).

var result = (from x in data.Worksheet("Tradesmen")
                         select x)**.ToList();**

Comment: I guess you mean where `i.workingStatus != j.WorkingStatus` right?

Comment: just to be sure if I understand you correctly, should your last line be this `select new { Name = i.Name, Code= i.Code, OldWorkingStatus = i.WorkingStatus, NewWorkingStatus = j.WorkingStatus }).ToList();` ?

Comment: Yes,i have changed it

Comment: wait please, I got this exception: `LinqToExcel does not provide support for the Join() method` it seems that results and resultNew is linkToExcel options :( :( not datatable, could you help?

Comment: can we build a datatabe? like i showed you in the question but instead of lists, we make a datatable?

Comment: I found something interesting, you said `resullt` and `resultnew` are lists, while I wrote that they are datatabe, did you mean to use the `masterEmployee` and `newEmployee` lists?

Comment: after your udpate, the program works, but the result is not correct, for example, I changed the working status manually for an employee but your `changed` list is `count=0` why?

Comment: Did you changed it before or after this line:var result =... ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60713/discussion-between-george-vovos-and-anastasie-laurent).